# Using MoveRotation in Unity 3D to turn player towards a certain angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been told that `Rigidbody.MoveRotation` is the best way in Unity 3D to rotate the player between fixed positions while still detecting hits. However, while I can move smoothly from fixed position to position with:

```
if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, targetPos) > 0.0455f) //FIXES JITTER 
            {
                var direction = targetPos - rb.transform.position;
                rb.MovePosition(transform.position + direction.normalized * playerSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            }
```

I can't find out how to rotate smoothly between fixed positions. I can rotate to the angle I want instantly using `Rigidbody.MoveRotation(Vector3 target);`, but I can't seem to find a way to do the above as a rotation.

Note: `Vector3.Distance` is the only thing stopping jitter. Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can go one step further and use a tweeting library to tween between rotations.

[DOTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php)

With that you can call it like this:

`rigidbody.DoRotate(target, 1f)` to rotate to target in 1 second.

Or even add callbacks.

`rigidbody.DoRotate(target, 1f).OnComplete(//any method or lambda you want)`

If at some point you want to cancel the tween yuou can save it on a variable and then call `tween.Kill();`

Comment: I doubt this will work together with Physics ... you need to **NOT** go through the `transform` but rather the `Rigidbody` component like OP does and it has to happen in `FixedUpdate` ... I don't think both can be done in DoTween ...

Comment: Also what if you want to continuously follow the target rather the only starting it once and then complete eventually?

Comment: Those cases are not part of the question, we can obviously make this as complex as we like.

Comment: OP specifically asks `rotate the player between fixed positions while still detecting hits` which pretty much requires intact physics without DOTween breaking them since it operates directly on `transform`. And this `var direction = targetPos - rb.transform.position;` can pretty much mean that player or target are moved in the meantime

Comment: Hits means detecting collisions and triggers, fundamentally you can't never move between A and B if you have a wall in between, you can even Kill the tween if a collision or trigger is detected, problem is not code, problem is the approach to the problem.

Comment: .. er no .. you might still want to push objects around or simply have certain triggers react to your collider without blocking the player from moving ... The issue is that tween operates on the transform directly which might prevent the collisions from even being detected in the first place so you wouldn't be able to `kill the tween` .. further `MovePosition` prevents exactly this and if a collision is detected you can not move further exactly .. with tween I would expect it to still pass the wall anyway

Comment: You know you can create your own tween and tween rigidbodies right? XD

Comment: Well, maybe, but you are suggesting `transform.DoRotate(target, 1f)` which I am referring to which doesn't do this an breaks with physics

Comment: I will update to be obvious to use rigidbody

Answer (score 0):

First of all [`MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) doesn't take a `Vector3` but rather a `Quaternion`.

Then in general your jitter might come from **overshooting** - you might be moving further than the distance between your player and target actually is.

You can avoid that bit by using [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) which prevents any overshooting of the target position like e.g.

```
Rigidbody rb;
float playerSpeed;
Vector3 targetPos;

// in general ONLY g through the Rigidbody as soon as dealing wit Physics
// do NOT go through transform at all
var currentPosition = rb.position;
// This moves with linear speed towards the target WITHOUT overshooting
// Note: It is recommended to always use "Time.deltaTime". It is correct also during "FixedUpdate"
var newPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPosition, targetPos, playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
rb.MovePosition(newPosition);

// [optionally]
// Note: Vector3 == Vector3 uses approximation with a precision of 1e-5
if(rb.position == targetPos)
{
    Debug.Log("Arrived at target!");
}
```

---

Then you can simply apply this same concept also to rotation by going through the equivalent [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) basically just the same approach

```
Rigidbody rb;
float anglePerSecond;
Quaternion targetRotation;

var currentRotation = rb.rotation;
var newRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(currentRotation, targetRotation, anglePerSecond * Time.deltaTime);
rb.MoveRotation(newRotation);

// [optionally]
// tests whether dot product is close to 1
if(rb.rotation == targetRotation)
{
    Debug.Log("Arrived at rotation!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I may try that

Answer (score -2):

So, you want to animate the rotation value over time until it reaches a certain value.

Inside the Update method, you can use the Lerp method to keep rotating the object to a point, but you will never really reach this point if you use Lerp. It will keep rotating forever (always closer to the point).

You can use the following:

```
private bool rotating = true;
public void Update()
{
    if (rotating)
    {
        Vector3 to = new Vector3(20, 20, 20);
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.eulerAngles, to) > 0.01f)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.rotation.eulerAngles, to, Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = to;
            rotating = false;
        }
    }
 
}
```

So, if the distance between the current object angle and the desired angle is greater than 0.01f, it jumps right to the desired position and stop executing the Lerp method.

Comment: a) when using Physics you want to **NOT** go through `transform` but rather the `Rigidbody` component like OP does already. You also want to do this in `FixedUpdate`. b) You do not want to go through [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) when animating continuously -> `Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.`

Comment: Interesting, Thanks for sharing this, it's always nice to learn improved techniques